# Ajax request return field without name attribute

Tags: forms, ajax

Instead of getting multiselect on making ajax request while I select content type, I got single select and this select hasn't any name (select tag hasn't attribute name). So here's problem and I don't know how to fix it. Can anybody help?

```
$form['export_what'] = array(
    '#type'  => 'select',
    '#multiple' => FALSE,
    '#title' => t('Select content type'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $form['export_what1_options']['#value'],
    '#ajax'    => array(
        'callback' => 'insttance_ajax_fill_content',
        'wrapper' => 'replace_model_div',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event'  => 'change',
    ),
);


$form['export_data'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_model_div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => $content,
);


function insttance_ajax_fill_content($form, $form_state)
{
    $i = $form['count_field']['#value'];
    $content = getAllContentByType($form_state['values']['export_what']);

    $form['export_data'] = array(        
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_model_div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#options' => $content,
    );

    return $form['export_data'];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'this select hasn't any name' ?

Comment: @JimmyKo select tag hasn't attribute name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute name is missing because you have replaced the select element in ajax callback. You just need to update the `#options`

```php
function insttance_ajax_fill_content($form, $form_state)
{
    $i = $form['count_field']['#value'];
    $content = getAllContentByType($form_state['values']['export_what']);

    $form['export_data']['#options'] = $content;

    return $form['export_data'];
}
```